# How to process node move event with EventListener in AEM? Duplicate calls occurs

Tags: events, osgi, aem, jcr

I have service that implements  javax.jcr.observation.EventListener. This service is listening the following event types:

- Event.NODE_MOVED
- Event.NODE_REMOVED

When I move node  `myCustomCodeToExecute()` method is triggered twice.

Is there a way to trigger my code only once if someone moves node?

```
    executor.submit(() -> {
        List<Event> eventsList = IteratorUtils.toList(eventIterator);
        for (final Event event : eventsList) {
            try {
                myCustomCodeToExecute()
            } catch (Exception e) {
                LOGGER.error("Can't send event", e);
            }
        }
    });
```

REMOVE event works as expected

Comment: I think you might be adding multiple/multi-level nodes causing multiple events to be emitted. try printing `event.getInfo()` and see if thy are same.

Comment: @awd both executions a relative to the same node. I have moved a leaf, there is no multi-level depth.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found an solution:

```
@Override
public void onEvent(EventIterator eventIterator) {
    executor.submit(() -> {
        List<Event> eventsList = IteratorUtils.toList(eventIterator);
        for (final Event event : eventsList) {
            try {
                if (eventType == Event.NODE_REMOVED) {
                    if (eventsList.stream().noneMatch(e -> Event.NODE_MOVED == e.getType())) {
                         //remove event
                    }
                         //move event will be processed in next iteration
                         continue;
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                LOGGER.error("Can't send event", e);
            }
        }
    });
}
```